# SqlConnection not being able to open the connection

Tags: c#, asp.net, database-connection, freesqldatabase

### What I have

1. An account in http://www.freesqldatabase.com
2. A database (**DB_DATABASE** var in my asp.net application)
3. An user and password for the DB (**DB_USER**, **DB_PASS**)
4. An Host URL (sql4.freesqldatabase.com [**DB_SERVER**])
5. A catalog, plus three tables (**DB_CATALOG**)
6. A port (**DB_PORT**)

### What I aim

To connect from my asp.net app, to my database.

### What have I tried

I tried to build a `SqlConnection`, just like:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(" + DB_SERVER + "\\" + DB_DATABASE + "," + DB_PORT + ");Initial Catalog=" + DB_CATALOG + ";UID=" + DB_USER + ";PWD=" + DB_PASS + ";");
```

I've used `DB_DATABASE` as the instance name, but I'm not sure about that (any explanation to clarify me this mess would be apreciated!)

But I've also tried without it:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(" + DB_SERVER + "," + DB_PORT + ");Initial Catalog=" + DB_CATALOG + ";UID=" + DB_USER + ";PWD=" + DB_PASS + ";");
```

And several options besides these ones, trying to modify the connection string, but no one has worked yet =(

### What I obtain

Well, when I'm trying to open the connection, I'm getting the following exception (I've tried to look for any useful data here, but I'm not used to this yet...):

```
   en System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   en System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   en System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity, Boolean withFailover)
   en System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover)
   en System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout)
   en System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
   en System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData)
   en System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   en System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   en System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   en System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   en System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   en System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   en System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   en System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   en System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   en System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   en System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   en System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   en Gallery.Gallery.registerNewUser(String username, String encripted_password)
```

### Plus, Found out

At http://www.freesqldatabase.com/category/net/ , they said they've said:

> Due to a bug within some MySQL connectors, the ‘Out of sync with server’ error is returned.
>
> To resolve this, use a different version of the MySQL connector.

But since I've seen nothing about this in the exception stacktrace, I'm not sure if I'm being affected by this (plus it's 2011 news).

**Did I do something wrong when building the connection?** How can I fix it?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All objects starting with "Sql" such as "SqlConnection", "SqlCommand", etc. are made for SQL Server. Apparently you are using MySQL so you need a different provider: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/

Once you add this provider as a reference in your project, you will be able to use "MySqlConnection", "MySqlCommand", etc.